# Having difficulty with a global variable in android application

Tags: android, class, variables, global

Hey I am having trouble declaring, changing, and using a global variable. I tried the whole "make a class that extends your application and put variables there" thing but I'm not sure how to implement it. Here is my class with the variable in it.

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {

    public int listPos;

}
```

I then tried to access and change int listPos here.

```
public class Browse extends ListActivity{
MyApp app = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String[] coffeeTypes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.coffeeTypes);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview, coffeeTypes));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        app.listPos = position;
        startActivity(new Intent(Browse.this, CoffeeTypes.class));

    }
  });
}
```

}

Then I tried to access the variable in the following activity to determine the outcome of an if else statement

```
public class CoffeeTypes extends Activity{
MyApp app = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  if(app.listPos == 0){
      Toast.makeText(this, "WEEEEEEE!0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  else if(app.listPos == 1){
      Toast.makeText(this, "RAWR!1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use soorya's answer with some modifications. I would personally still use your myApp class but change listPos to static and access it that way. Doing it this way lets you use the Application class `onCreate` method to initialize values if needed (though it won't be needed in this example) or other Android methods.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static int listPos;

}

//~~ Elsewhere:
MyApp.listPos = 5; //etc
```

But this isn't the best way to handle your type of problem.

You should be passing the list position information (or the id of the item clicked or however you are handling your data) via the `Intent`.

Instead of having a global variable to track this information, keep it local to just the Intent:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        //app.listPos = position;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Browse.this, CoffeeTypes.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(intent);
        //startActivity(new Intent(Browse.this, CoffeeTypes.class));

    }
```

This passes the position data to the new Activity via the intent. In your CoffeeTypes Activity you should start with something along the following:

```
//in onCreate...
int incomingPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",-1));
if(incomingPosition != -1) { //do stuff }
```

This will read the "position" data from the incoming Intent so you can use it. The -1 above is the default value if nothing is added.

One final warning: you might want to be careful sending the list position back and forth, depending on how your application is set up if new items are added/items are deleted the list position might no longer refer to the item you thought it did. If these coffee types/whatever you are using have a separate unique ID that might be more appropriate to avoiding the above situation, consider using that instead.

Comment: Awesome help! Although now my app is crashing for some unknown reason, but your right about the intent. Much easier.

Comment: @Seeshi_suin I forgot to add a modified version of startActivity, edited now. Might not be related to your new problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a visibility issue with the android OS, are you able to make an public functions that may be able to act as getters for the variable?

```
int getListPos(){ return this.listpos; }
```

I know that you can pass variables between contexts, you may have to do that.

Perhaps a temporary workaround to get you moving could be creating a static class of accessible variables too?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this

```
class globalClass
{
       static int lastPos;
}
```

You can set values using

```
globalClass.lastPos = value;
```

and get function is

```
int myVal = globalClass.lastPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

i do Application variable classes by making the variables private, and then create public get() and set() methods to change the variables. you can try that, but it seems like you are doing it right, technically

one reason why it might be going wrong is because you are implementing the stuff in onCreate and not onStartCommand. if you are testing this function with the wrong assumptions/knowledge of the Activity cycle, it could go wrong